Checkbox doesn't want to align left with others elements (Flutter)
i'm actually coding an app with Flutter.
I've a problem with my Checkbox, I don't understand why it doesn't want to align with others elements.
There is a gap between the padding and the checkbox that I don't understand.
Here is the full code of what i'm talking about.
Full Code
I want the Row() who contains the Checkbox and the Text.rich() to align on the left with the same gap between the edge of the screen as others elements in my page.
Here is an image of what it's actually looking like, as you can see, there is an unexpected gap.
App in an emulator
The red line represents where i want everything to align.
Thx for your help in advance !
Edit : (full code of my actual page where I want to had the checkbox)
import 'package:db_todoapp/components/my_button.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/components/my_password_textfield.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/components/my_textfield.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/utilities/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:grain/grain.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function()? togglePage;
  const RegisterPage({
    super.key,
    required this.togglePage,
  });

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPasswordController =
      TextEditingController();
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Background
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: GrainFiltered(
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.2,
                child: Image.asset("assets/login background.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // Content
          SafeArea(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverFillRemaining(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 25.0,
                      left: 25.0,
                      right: 25.0,
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 25.0,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // Texte "Connextion"
                        Text(
                          "Inscription",
                          style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xFFAD4352),
                          ),
                        ),

                        const Gap(25),

                        // Textfield nom d'utilisateur
                        MyTextfield(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          controller: usernameController,
                          hintText: "Nom d'utilisateur",
                          isOneLine: true,
                          maxLenght: null,
                        ),

                        const Gap(10),

                        // Textfield email
                        MyTextfield(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          controller: emailController,
                          hintText: "Adresse e-mail",
                          isOneLine: true,
                          maxLenght: null,
                        ),

                        const Gap(10),

                        // Textfield password
                        MyPasswordTextfield(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          controller: passwordController,
                          hintText: "Mot de passe",
                        ),

                        const Gap(10),

                        // Textfield confirmer son mot de passe
                        MyPasswordTextfield(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          controller: confirmPasswordController,
                          hintText: "Confirmez votre mot de passe",
                        ),

                        const Gap(25),

                        // Bouton "Se connecter"
                        MyButton(
                          color: const Color(0xFFB14348),
                          text: "S'inscrire",
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          onTap: () {
                            _auth.signUp(
                              context,
                              usernameController.text.trim(),
                              emailController.text.trim(),
                              passwordController.text.trim(),
                              confirmPasswordController.text.trim(),
                            );
                          },
                        ),

                        const Gap(10),

                        // Aucun compte existant ? Créer un compte
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const Text("Déjà un compte ? "),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: widget.togglePage,
                              child: const Text(
                                "Se connecter",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


wrapping widgets with a colorfull container may help you to identify issues with padding and widget space.

Instead of using a Row for checkbox and text why don't  you use CheckBoxListTile With leading affinity and content padding zero


CheckboxListTile(
 controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
 title: Text('Remember Me'),
 value: false,
 onChanged: (V) {},
 activeColor: const Color(0xFFB14248),
),




I tried it but I still have a gap.

can you share with me the whole code

I'm not actually at home, but I will share it as soon as I can.

I just edited my questions where I linked all of the code of my page.
It doesn't contain any more the checkbox but I want to had it btetween the widget commented as "TextField confirmer son mot de passe" and "Bouton "Se connecter".

This is default in Flutter , you can use this --
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {},
child: Icon(
onTap ? Icons.check_box_outline_blank: Icons.check_box_outlined
),
),
-- and in the icon you can add condition and on tap you can  update the icon as per the condition because flutter checkbox has some default padding otherwise you can use this
-Transform.translate(
offset: const Offset(-13, 0),
child: Checkbox(...),
)
